# how to find outliers from high-dimensional data set?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, data-mining, outliers

The data has about 40 features and 500,000 instances. And the data is sparse. I wish to fit a svm model with the data. To fit svm, I need to first scale the data. However, if the data contains many outliers, scaling is likely to not work very well. So the problem is how can I find outliers in the data?

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried already? Can you provide a scree-plot of your data? Standard PCA algorithms are fine for your case. Your data is barely above 152 MBytes (even if you treat them as dense) to begin with. To that aspect try a sparse PCA algorithm too.

Comment: If you can formalize "not work well", then you can use that definition as a metric for "outlier".

Comment: @usεr11852 Because the data is 40-features, it is hard to have a plot. If I could, I would find the outliers in this way. Could you explain how PCA can find outliers?

Comment: Please check what a scree-plot is; I am not asking for a 40-dimensional scatter plot. Screeplots are by far some of the simplest plots to create and should always be examined in a dimension reduction task.

Comment: @Neil G could you explain how? Because the data has many instances, how can I **find** outliers by knowing scaling "not work well"?

Comment: @XiangZhang: Can you first explain what you mean by "not work well"?  Then I can explain how you find the "outliers".

Comment: @usεr11852 I got it. You are saying PCA can be used for dimension reduction. But I doubt if the outliers will be removed in this way. Scree-plot is useful for attributes selection but maybe not for finding outliers?

Comment: Can we see it? Also can you try a robust PCA variant? If the few few modes of variation encapsulate most of your variance you can exclude the rest of them as being noise.

Comment: @Neil G Well, if the data has three attributes and there are some instances like [1,2,1], [-0.5,0,1],[0.5,-1,0.5], another instance is [-0.5,1,100]. It seems that the last instance is an outlier. If I wish to scale the data to [-1,1], the third column will be influenced by the outlier and the result will be [1,1,0.01],[-0.5,0,0.01],[0.5,-0.5,0.005],[-0.5,0.5,1]. If I remove the fourth instance then the result will be [1,1,1],[-0.5,0,1],[0.5,-0.5,0.5].

Comment: @XiangZhang: There is no reason why such a data point should not be fit by your algorithm.  Does such data not occur in your testing set?  Is it not important to fit this data?  If you can explain why things are better when you remove this data point, then you will have your answer as to when to remove it.

Comment: .... Just use OGK (Orthogonalized Gnanadesikan-Kettenring) and/or MCD (minimum covariance determinant ) and pick the most coherent. And having 40 dimensions is just "multivariate".

Comment: Many threads here on outliers: did you search before you posted? It's hard to summarize, but the negative principle I would mention first is that there is no simple universal definition of outliers. Outliers are defined only relative to some model, even if it's tacit or informal.

Comment: If you just want a resistant method to scale the data, then why not use one?  The IQR will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the Mahalanobis distance for each observation.  If $S$ is the estimated covariance matrix of the data and $\overline{x}$ is its mean (vector), for item ${\bf x_i}$ the distance is $D_i = ({\bf x_i}-\mu)^\prime S^{-1}({\bf x_i}-\mu)$. If your data is multivariate normal, these distances will have values that are chi-square distributed with 40 (= number of features) degrees of freedom.  So compare the distances with the 95th percentile of the chi-square random variable.

Comment: In fairness Mahalanobis distance is susceptible to outliers so I am not sure if this metric should be your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Following up @AlaskaRon's answer (and comments): [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022103117302123) suggests a robust analogue of the Mahalanobis distance called the *Minimum Covariance Determinant*:

> The MCD estimators of location and scatter, denoted $\hat\mu_{MCD}$ and $\hat \Sigma_{MCD}$, correspond to the sample mean and covariance matrix of this most central sub-sample.

e.g. via the `covMcd` function in R's [robustbase package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=robustbase) ... so, compute the MCD and pick some sensible threshold ...